# How can I determine related models from a model instance?

Tags: django, foreign-key-relationship

```
Class A(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(...)


Class B(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey('A')
    more_text = models.CharField(...)
```

1. I have an instance of `A`.
2. I can get all the fields using `instance._meta.fields`.
3. I can get the `many_to_many` fields using `instance._meta.many_to_many`.

How can I get related models? (In a generic way)

The reason I want this, is because if I want to display an instance of `A` on a template, `A` is incomplete without the foreign key relationship from `B`.

Comment: But if you just want to show the value of this field couldn't you just add it in a function like __unicode__?

Comment: do you want related models name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem a few days ago:

The models are like this:

```
from model_utils.managers import InheritanceManager

Class A(models.Model):
    """
    @documention
    """
    text = models.CharField(...)
    related_content = models.ManyToManyField(
        "self", null=True, blank=True, )
    objects = InheritanceManager()


Class B(models.Model):
    """
    @documention
    """
    a = models.ForeignKey('A')
    more_text = models.CharField(...)
```

Pay attention to the InheritanceManager

```
class BDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    """
    @documention
    """
    model = B

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['related_content'] = A.objects.filter(
            related_content=self.object).select_subclasses()
        return context
```

Using model_utils, I am able to get the actual related models, instead of 'A' instances (which have a lot of specific content missing)

Answer (score 1):

1) First guess about what did you mean:

```
models.ForeignKey('A', related_name='my_model_b')
```

then in template you can `{{ a.my_model_b_set.all }}` it will be all B-objects attached to a given A-object.

2) Second guess about what did you mean:

If you have a form where you create **B** object and you need something like "pre-save" connection to object of **A** then you need to send via AJAX call chosen **A** object and do something further (for example filter choices in another Fk-field in this model)

Answer (score 1):

this give you name of all related models:

```
models = [r.var_name for r in a_obj._meta.get_all_related_objects()]
```